# Sync core data between iOS devices over wifi?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, asyncsocket

I want to sync Core Data between iOS devices over wifi. I know how to make a connection with ASyncSockets, but I'm not sure of the next step - syncing the core data.

I'm aware of the ZSync project for syncing between iOS and Mac, but I was wondering if anybody knew if it was possible to do the same thing between iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could tackle this in several ways, but I would consider one of these two:

1. Take an `NSManagedObject` subclass' properties, convert them to `NSData`, and use AsyncSocket to transfer them. Then, when the receiving app has received all properties, it recreates the object in its own database.
2. Transfer your entire database at once. No need to recreate anything.

The first option has the advantage that it only sends over what it needs to. If you have thousands of objects, and you change one, you only transfer that one object. On the other hand, things can get really complicated if you have several relationships on that one object as you will have to send the related objects over as well.

The second option is the easiest for you, but is not very efficient. If you change one object, you are sending over the entire database. If your database is several megabytes in size, that could take a while, and you're doing it every time you make a change.

Ideally, you do it the way iCloud does it. Only push/pull things that have changed. I don't know the implementation of how iCloud determines that, but I bet it's not something trivial. Whichever method works best for you depends on how big your database is and how often objects are modified. Method 2 works best for a big, complicated database with few modifications, method 1 if your database is relatively simple (no or few relationships) and undergoes a lot of changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can go over the web I would definitely go with iCloud, that handles this for you in an efficient way. If your app should be able to work on wifi only, maybe you can reimplement the same behaviour of iCloud. The way it works is described in the document [*Using Core Data with iCloud Programming Notes*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011298):

> In iOS 5, Core Data includes enhancements to support efficient integration of the SQLite store with iCloud. The principal new feature is that each change you commit to a persistent store is recorded in discrete transaction log files that are stored in iCloud, rather than keeping the persistent store file in the cloud directly. This means that change propagation through iCloud is efficient (the alternative would be to push the whole SQLite file for each change).